# How to keep null values when using `Array.join()`?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following,

```
const arr = [ 1, 5, null, null, 10 ];
console.log(arr.join(',')); // '1,5,,,10'
console.log(`${arr}`); // '1,5,,,10'
```

I need to keep these `null` values, how can I do this?

Only thing I could think of is something with `reduce`,

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, el, index, self) => `${acc += el}${index !== self.length - 1 ? ',' : ''}`, '');
```

Any better way?

Comment: What would be the use case for this, though? Like, why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: A parameterized db query builder, in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, null, null, 10 ];
const jin = arr.reduce((p, c) => `${p},${c}`);

console.log(jin);
```

---

#### Using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Or use `map()` with `String` function to convert *each value* to a string so that `join()` will keep it:

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, null, null, 10 ];
const jin = arr.map(String).join(',');

console.log(jin);
```

#### Output

```
1,5,null,null,10
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a pretty answer, but you could turn the nulls to strings.

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, null, null, 10 ];
const arr2 = arr.map(x => String(x));
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr2.join(','));
```

Comment: btw, `arr.map(String)` is shorter.

Comment: @NinaScholz Indeed, but it seems someone else already used that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, null, null, 10 ]
console.log(String(arr.map(String)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map everything to strings first by concatenating with an empty string:

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, null, null, 10 ];
console.log(arr.map((item) => item + "").join(',')); // '1,5,null,null,10'
console.log(`${arr}`); // '1,5,,,10'
```